# Is it possible to find a general solution to $\vec{\theta}(L) = \mathbf{M} \vec{\theta}(0)$, when there are unknowns on both sides of the equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the context of a transport scheme in condensed matter physics, I am facing the following problem:

Imagine a system in which thermal power is transported in $k$ channels in downstream (ds) and in $N-k$ channels in upstream (us) direction. Between pairs of ds and us channels tunneling is allowed leading to equilibration of counter-propagating channels. To compute thermal currents in this system, one needs to solve the system of Eqs. for the boundary conditions of the squares of the temperatures $\theta$ given by

$$ \vec{\theta}(L) = \begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{\vec{\theta}_{\rm ds}(L)} \\ \color{green}{\vec{\theta}_{\rm us}(L)} \end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{M} \begin{pmatrix} \color{green}{\vec{\theta}_{\rm ds}(0)} \\ \color{red}{\vec{\theta}_{\rm us}(0)} \end{pmatrix} ,$$

where $ \mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is a matrix with known elements $m_{ij}$, for $\vec{\theta}_{\rm ds}(L)$ (there exist some symmetry related conditions for the elements $m_{ij}$ which I don't state here). Unfortunately the known boundary conditions (green) are on opposite sites of the equation and the red ones are unknown. In particular they are given by

$$ \vec{\theta}_{i \in \rm ds}(0) = \theta_L$$
$$ \vec{\theta}_{i \in \rm us}(L) = \theta_R$$

Is it possible to find a general solution for $\vec{\theta}_{\rm ds}(L)$?
For a system of known size this is quite straightforward but for an arbitrary, yet finite sized system (size: $N$), I have some difficulties ^^

So far I tried to find closed expressions in component form. I used that the inverse  $(\mathbf{M})^{-1}$ (which always exists and is square) is given by ${\rm adj}(\mathbf{M})/{\rm det}(\mathbf{M})$ and the expansion of the determinant by minors. Very soon I ran into some very nasty expressions which I couldn't simplify any further. I think this was perhaps not the best approach. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathbf{M}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\xA}{\color{green}{\vec{\theta}_{\textrm{ds}}(0)}}
\newcommand{\xB}{\color{green}{\vec{\theta}_{\textrm{us}}(L)}}
\newcommand{\yA}{\color{red}{\vec{\theta}_{\textrm{ds}}(L)}}
\newcommand{\yB}{\color{red}{\vec{\theta}_{\textrm{us}}(0)}}$Assuming I understood you correctly, you are given the downstream temperatures $\xA\in\R^{k}$ on the left and the upstream temperatures $\xB\in\R^{N-k}$ on the right of the material; and you are looking for both downstream temperatures $\yA\in\R^{k}$ on the right and upstream temperatures $\yB\in\R^{N-k}$ on the left of the material.

My answer depends a little on the properties of the matrix $\M\in\R^{N\times N}$.
We will write it in block matrix form. Then your equation becomes:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \yA \\ \xB
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\M
\begin{pmatrix}
  \xA \\ \yB
\end{pmatrix}
=
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\A  &  \B\\\hline
\C  &  \D
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
  \xA \\ \yB
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \A\xA + \B\yB \\ \C\xA + \D\yB
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where
$\A\in\R^{k\times k}$,
$\B\in\R^{k\times (N-k)}$,
$\C\in\R^{(N-k)\times k}$,
$\D\in\R^{(N-k)\times (N-k)}$.

We can rearrange these equations into:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \yA - \B\yB \\ -\D\yB
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
  \A\xA \\ \C\xA-\xB
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\operatorname{Id}_{k}  &  -\B\\\hline
0  &  -\D
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
  \yA \\ \yB
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\A  &  0\\\hline
\C  &  -\operatorname{Id}_{N-k}
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
  \xA \\ \xB
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

If you know that the $(N-k)\times(N-k)$ submatrix $\D$ of your matrix $\M$ is invertible, then you can invert the matrix on the left and you obtain the following solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \yA \\ \yB
\end{pmatrix}
&= 
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\operatorname{Id}_{k}  &  -\B\\\hline
0  &  -\D
\end{array}\right)
^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\A  &  0\\\hline
\C  &  -\operatorname{Id}_{N-k}
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
  \xA \\ \xB
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\operatorname{Id}_{k}  &  -\B\D^{-1}\\\hline
0  &  -\D^{-1}
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\A  &  0\\\hline
\C  &  -\operatorname{Id}_{N-k}
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
  \xA \\ \xB
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
\A - \B\D^{-1}\C  &  \B\D^{-1}\\\hline
-\D^{-1}\C  &  \D^{-1}
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
  \xA \\ \xB
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

In general, if $\D$ has rank $r$ then you can only hope for a solution space of dimension $N-k-r$, if a solution exists at all.

Comment: You are absolutely correct with your assumption about the system :)
I actually got to a very similar solution like yours - luckily all of the matrices are (I will double check) invertible -> I think this is the solution I am looking for, thank you a lot :)
I will respond here again, once I checked the result for some cases that I know the solution to

Comment: I didn't mess up the question, it works - thanks a lot!